# Change the Team Project Set import destination in Eclipse, STS, or RAD

Tags: java, eclipse, import, rad, spring-tool-suite

After researching, I can't find a way to change the default import location when importing a Team Project Set in either RAD, STS, or base Eclipse.

Currently it just dumps the projects into the workspace. I keep all of my projects on a separate drive so that when I change workspaces, I can hook into the projects folder and keep going.

I am trying to find a way to change the Team Project Set import so that I can import into the projects folder instead of the workspace.

Has anyone else figured out how to do so or know that it just isn't possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that is a limitation of that import wizard. What about filing a bug/enhancement request at Eclipse for that? https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/